# ViewPager открытый, готовый код

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Подскажите где найти код для красивого ViewPager.
Что то вроде вот этого:

[Что-то вроде этого](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager)

Этот бы и подошел, но как то не могу подредактировать под себя, сложный какой то:)
Всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Спасибо elik за ответ!
А можно ещё примерчик красивого Spinner? Стандартный уж совсем не очень, даже рамочки нет

Comment: ну со спинором то щас беда )н ща посммотрю

Comment: Вот и сам спиннер)более кастомный он тип навороченный)

Comment: https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner

Comment: если мой нижний ответ пригодился поставь галочку ответ верный )мне в карму будет)

Answer (score 1):

Вот сам пользуюсь ими ,хотя они нуждаются в коррекции 
1-ая:

[Первый ТаБ](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

а вот и 2-ой:

[Советую этот](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs)